# how to query and / or update xml column in mysql

Tags: mysql, xml, select, updates

I have an XML column in a MySQL database that contains a structure compared to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ParamaterInfoTestClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!-- left out the non important elements -->
  <TickerInfo>
    <TickerId>15</TickerId>
    <IsvId>5</IsvId>
    <Ticker>SomeTicker</Ticker>
    <IsvName>SomeIsv</IsvName>
  </TickerInfo>
  <Benchmark>
    <TickerId>10</TickerId>
    <IsvId>5</IsvId>
    <Ticker>AnotherTicker</Ticker>
    <IsvName>SomeIsv</IsvName>
  </Benchmark>
  <BarSize>000100</BarSize>
  <SomeIdElement>1</SomeIdElement>
</ParamaterInfoTestClass>
```

How can I query this column in a way so I get all of the Ticker Elements.
I know how to get the value based on a parent element. Like this:

```
SELECT `id`,ExtractValue(`xmlstring`, '/ParamaterInfoTestClass/TickerInfo/Ticker') AS result FROM `XMLTest`;
```

**Question 1:**
Is it possible to get both tickers (read all; if there are more elements with the tickerId sub element) from the TickerInfo and Benchmark elements **without** knowing their names in advance. So, more or less based on a wildcard and linked to SomeIdElement (meaning, having SomeIdElement on the same row as the result of ticker)

**Question 2:**
How can I update every Ticker (sub) element in a xml column. Say the ticker changes from ABC to XYZ and I need to update all alements. Normally U would use something like

```
UPDATE `XMLTest` SET `xmlstring` = UpdateXml(`xmlstring`,'/ParamaterInfoTestClass/TickerInfo/Ticker','<Ticker>XYZ</Ticker>') where ExtractValue(`xmlstring`,'/ParamaterInfoTestClass/TickerInfo/Ticker')='ABC';
```

But in this case (just like the above case) I need to know every element preceding the Ticker element, to be able to update the XML. I would like to be able to update all Ticker element at once, without knowing the exact structure in advance and also when the XML content contains the specific value multiple times.
Can that be done, if so...how?

**Question 3:**
how can I get the XML sub elements / structure with a query?
I tried this:

```
SELECT ExtractValue(`xmlstring`, '/ParamaterInfoTestClass/TickerInfo') AS result FROM `XMLTest`;
```

Kind regards,

Matthijs

Comment: q1: as per the docs: `If multiple matches are found, the content of the first child text node of each matching element is returned (in the order matched) as a single, space-delimited string.`

Comment: when I run this query SELECT `id`,ExtractValue(`xmlstring`, 'Ticker') AS result FROM `XMLTest`; it returns empty results.